# 3D Model material not loading properly in threejs

Tags: three.js, blender

I have created a dummy donut model using Blender. This is how it looks in Blender after I render it.
[image]

When I import this donut model using Three.js framework. This is how it looks.
[image]

This is my code for loading the model.

```
import {Scene,
        PerspectiveCamera,
        WebGLRenderer,
        DirectionalLight,
        AxesHelper}  from "three";


// import {load_donut} from "./loadDonut.js"
import {GLTFLoader } from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

const scene = new Scene();
const camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({alpha:true, antialias:true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


load_donut();

const light = new DirectionalLight( 0xffffbb,1);
scene.add( light );


const axesHelper = new AxesHelper( 5 );
scene.add( axesHelper );

const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 5;
camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();

function load_donut(){
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        './donut_model.gltf',
        // called when the resource is loaded
        function ( gltf ) {
            
            scene.add(gltf.scene);

        },
        // called while loading is progressing
        function ( xhr ) {

            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {

            console.log( 'An error happened' );

        }
    );
}
```

**I have tried different lighting functions from three.js framework which improved the look slightly, but not too much. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this issue? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its your 3js problem... I think it's your model saving problem.
See what happens is your Blender is that you made it there so you can render it perfectly... but you might see problems when you export it.
It's Bcoz of some things like lighting, texture etc.
In your case as you said you already tried lightings... so may be that was not a problem

I think it's your texture or Scaling/Rotation,
Do something like

1. Verify that the model's materials and textures are properly assigned and configured in 3js. Check if the textures are correctly mapped and UV unwrapped in Blender and that the materials are set up correctly in Three.js.
2. heck if the model's scale and rotation are consistent between Blender and 3js. 3js might take these properties differently, causing the model to appear distorted or misplaced.

> FROM THE LOOKS OF IT... my personal advice... see in your 3js model some of those chocolates are appearing upside down...rt? Did you not merged your chocolate texture? it is showing in parts... in blender select only your chocolate texture... join/merge them properly and then check.